# How to overcome the HTTP Error 500 with MODISTools

Tags: r, http, r-modis

I have been using `MODISTools` , but have been facing `HTTP Error : 500` as of today. The version of R that I have been using is R version `4.1.0` (2021-05-18) and version of my `MODSITools` is `1.1.1.`

Even

`mt_dates(product = "MOD11A2", lat = 40, lon = -110)`

(https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MODISTools/versions/1.1.1/topics/mt_dates)

gives HTTP:500

Is waiting for some time the only solution?
Have anyone faced this issue earlier. If yes how was it resolved?

Thank you.

Comment: issue raised on github  https://github.com/ropensci/MODISTools/issues/27#issuecomment-694750006 Maybe raise new issue.

Comment: Thank you,  issue https://github.com/ropensci/MODISTools/issues/44 was raised yesterday, issue has been resolved today.